# Add content after text

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to add text by pseudo-selector ::after or ::before to a specyfic word?
For ex. I would like to add pdf icon always next to word "Download".
[PDF] Download

Or maybe is it another method?

Comment: No. You can only target elements, not text nodes.

Comment: you would have to wrap it in a span with a specific class and do it that way

Answer (score 20, accepted):

your link on pdf need contain pdf, then you could use this selector:

```css
a[href*="pdf"]:before {content: '[ICON] '}
a[href*="pdf"]:after {content: ' ';}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/test.pdf" class="pdf">learn html and css in one week</a>
```

Comment: this solution is wrong absolutely.Because select `href=http://pdfexample.com/test.doc`

Comment: @ehsan use another selector for `doc` or use for checking word in the end of href. My solution is just an example.

Comment: a[href*="pdf"] is meaning that select any `a` with href that ,it contain pdf.may is `pdf` be part of a word.

Comment: @ehsan there is a lot of other selectors `a[href$=".pdf"]` try to use google

Answer (score 3):

> You can use of `:after` or `:before` for insert `content` to Elements no text. my suggestion is wrap text in span with `class` and use `:after` or `:before`.

```css
.pdf:after {
  content: ' Download';
}
```

```html
<span class="pdf">[PDF]</span>
```

> For `a` Elements use `a[href$=".pdf"]`

```css
a[href$=".pdf"]:after {
  content: ' Download'
}
```

```html
<a href="http://e-book.com/css.pdf" class="pdf">Book</a>
```

Comment: It is good solution, but I would like to avoid taging each text. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Pat,this solution that you select is wrong absolutely.Because select href=pdfaidexample.com/test.doc